# Отображение времени в http, python

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Суть такая. Как организовать сервер на питоне так, чтобы отображалось окно с заголовком и текущим временем. В стататике я это сделал:
Hello, world!
09/15/2022, 13:46:01
но время обновляется только при обновлении страницы. Как сделать так, чтобы время обновлялось постоянно, без принудительного обновления пользователем страницы?

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from datetime import datetime

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    # определяем метод `do_GET`
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'<h1>Hello, world!</h1>')
        #while True:
        current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
        self.wfile.write(current_datetime.encode())

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Поставить специальный тэг для обновления страницы:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML in 10 Simple Steps or Less</title>
    <meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”1" />
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Внутри `body` - выводите ваше время. Но это очень нерационально - всё время перегружать целиком всю страницу. Хотя можно сделать `iframe` внутри страницы и перегружать только его, но вроде бы сейчас так уже никто не пишет.

2. Обновлять текст страницы с помощью `JavaScript`, забирая им данные с сервера. Но тут нужен код на `JavaScript`.